# I'm having problems with UnityEngine.TouchScreenKeyboard.visible

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm having a problem: UnityEngine.TouchScreenKeyboard.visible is = true even though the phone keyboard is not visible yet.
I've tried quite a few ways but it doesn't seem feasible. So is there any way to accurately check that the keyboard is completely visible?

Comment: I need to check if the keyboard is completely visible. Currently, the error is that the above variables return true but it takes a few hundred milliseconds for the keyboard to appear.

Comment: Does `TouchScreenKeyboard.active` work?

Comment: what is the resulting issue? Maybe you can work around it? ^^